# Node.js and Mongodb database on my server for android application

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, server

I am developing an android application using node.js and mongodb .I followed following link-
http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/04/android-login-registration-nodejs-server.html.
i am successful in running app with localhost on emulator.now i want to keep my database on server and to run app on any device.What steps are required to run node.js and mongodb database on server,and access it through android app using a url.
help appreciated.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. You may also want to see this article [How I Got Node.js and MongoDB running on Android](http://www.codemonkeez.com/2014/05/how-i-got-nodejs-and-mongodb-running-on.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running your Node.js and MongoDB on the **server** then you simply need to implement an HTTP client of some kind to access the server.

One simple way is to use a `WebView` so that you do not have to parse the results, etc. It is simply displayed in your app as a website would be.

Alternatively, you can use something like `Jsoup` or another HTML/XMl parser to parse page requests into data that your app uses.

Comment: i am asking how to run node.js and mongodb on sever?